# How to retrieve a value from a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm not sure if this is a complicated process, but I was hoping some could help!

I'm just building a project for myself to teach myself some nodeJS and restAPI! I'm trying to make a simple [BTC](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/), [LTC](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/), [ETH](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/), [BCH](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash/) app using Postman to view the prices by using restAPI calls.

I'm using MongoDB, and Express, as I used them for a school project. Now I'd like to advance some more, but this time I'm not quite sure about how to retrieve the value of the cryptocurrency.

I was wondering if this is too complicated, or what ways this can be done.

I used [this](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-design-with-node-js-26ccf66eab09) tutorial a while ago to help me through the project in school. I'm using the same set-up, but what I'd like to do goes beyond my knowledge. I would like to use the GET call in Postman as such:

http://localhost:3000/BTC

and have it return the value. of course this would all be done in the GET function, but as of now I'm stuck on how to retrieve a value from a website so that it's up to date.

If you guys could help me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Use the API to fetch the data you need: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser

Comment: You could map the `/BTC` endpoint to [an http request](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) to the api of your cryptocurrency, and return the value

Comment: Retrieveing or fetching values of crypto currencies is quite simple. You can use various open source apis for that, I would suggest this [Coin Market Cap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) You can find tutorials for this and their tutorials are also vary comprehensive. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the http module to make get requests and point them at coinmarketcap for your data - I have *very quickly* written an example of how to go about it - **untested**!

```
app.get('/btc', (req,res) => {
  let options = {host: 'coinmarketcap.com', path: '/ticker/1/'};

  http.get(options, (response) => {
    var output = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      output += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
      res.end(output);
    });
  });
});
```

If you want a good framework for creating REST apis, have a look at [feathersjs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/)
Feathers also can do websockets for realtime updates.